# Mac Eclipse hierarchical view also in com.example.test (package)

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, package

I have a question about the hierarchical view of eclipse. With some projects my com.example.test packages suddenly split where normally it would be on one line instead of three. It looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody know why this happens?

How can I get the com.example.test on one line again?

**Edit:**

I want the package presentation to be hierarchical, I only want the com.example.test back on one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer. It isn't folding because on mac there are hidden files (.DS_Store) and eclipse doesn't ignore these files, so the folders are not empty.

To fix this you have to exclude the DS_Store out of your project:

1. Right click, Properties
2. Expand Resource and click onto Resource Filters
3. Click "Add"
4. Use these settings Filter type: Exclude all.

   Applies to: Files

   Click "All children (recursive)"

   File and folder attributes: Name matches .DS_Store

If you have done this, your project will have normal hierarchal view with com.example.test.

Found the solution at: http://twigstechtips.blogspot.nl/2012/10/eclipse-ignore-certain-files-in-project.html

**Tip:** Use Android Studio, it works so much better!

Answer (score 1):

In the Package Explorer "View Menu" (the down arrow), select "Package Presentation" > "Flat".

Comment: I don't want the package presentation to be flat, I want the package presentation to be hierarchical. But the hierarchical shouldn't do the com.example.test, only the sub packages of that

Comment: You may try to check if "Fold empty packages in hierarchical layout in Package and Project Explorer" under Preferences > Java > Appearance is activated.

Comment: That is already checked. It is really weird, because some projects don't do it but sometimes it suddenly happens and I can't get it away.